# Inverse of symmetric matrix $AA^\top$ where $rank(A)=m \leq n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-rank

Suppose I have a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R^{m\times n}}$ where $m\leq n$ and $rank(A)=m$. Is the matrix $AA^\top$ singular?

My hunch is that the matrix is only non-singular when $n=m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the proof that the $m\times m$ matrix $AA^\top$ is nonsingular. Suppose $AA^\top x = 0$ for some vector $x\in\Bbb R^m$. Then
$$0=(AA^\top x)\cdot x = A^\top x\cdot A^\top x$$
by the fundamental property of transpose. This means that $A^\top x = 0$. Since $A^\top$ is an $n\times m$ matrix with rank $m$, the only solution of this equation is $x=0$. (For example, the only linear combination of the columns of $A^\top$ that gives the zero vector is the zero linear combination.) This means that $AA^\top$ is in fact nonsingular.

Comment: yeah, I was thinking of mentioning positive definite, with a comment that row rank equals column rank. At that point, I was taking a shower, and had not taken the keyboard with me.

Comment: I'm sure your keyboard is grateful, @WillJagy!

Answer (score 0):

Let $$A= \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0  \end{bmatrix}$$

then we have $AA^T=1$.

In general,
$$rank(AA^T)=rank(A)=m,$$

hence, it is nonsingular.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, with your symbols, $A A^T$ is non-singular, it is $m$ by $m.$

The square $A^T A$ is a square matrix of size $n$ by $n$ but rank $m,$ therfore singular when $m < n$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how do I _prove_ that $AA^\top$ is non-singular, in general? I'm from a CS background, not a maths background, so I might be missing some fundamental knowledge here.